# make the browser window as same as the element's size while resizing browser window. or atleast maintain same aspect ratio of browser as element have

Tags: javascript, html, css

while resizing my browser window i can resize the element div in it. But unwanted spaces/scope on left, right, top and bottom are appearing. I want the browser window's size as same as the div have. Or atleast find the aspect ratio of a div and accordingly we maintain same aspect ratio of the browser window. Ex: if div aspect ratio is 16:9, then we make the browser aspect ratio also same so that we can remove the unwanted space/scope in the browser window.

This is a sample script, instead of using div im using canvas. Help me with this.

```
<style>
*{padding:0; margin:0}
html,body {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#main {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 963px;
height: 642px;
}
#preload {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin:auto
}
.loading {
position:absolute;
top: 43%;
left: 47%;
z-index: 2;
display: none;
}
section{
position:absolute;
top:0
}
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5{display:block}
</style>
<div id="main">
    <img id="preload" src="preload.jpg"/>
    <img class="loading" src="image.jpg" />

    <section>
        <a1></a1>
        <a2></a2>
        <a3></a3>
    </section>
</div>

<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>



<script>        
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var maxWidth = $(window).width();
        var maxHeight = $(window).height();

        var ratio = $("#main").height() / $("#main").width();

        if(maxWidth * ratio > maxHeight) {
            $("#main").height(maxHeight);
            $("#main").width(maxHeight / ratio);
        } else {
            $("#main").width(maxWidth);
            $("#main").height(maxWidth * ratio);
        }
        $("#preload").width($("#main").width());
        $("#preload").height($("#main").height());

        $("a1").text(maxWidth);
        $("a2").text(maxHeight);
        $("a3").text(ratio);        
    }).trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for but you can set any element to fill the browser like so...

```
.element{
width:100%;
height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: what i need is, element maintains 16:9 aspect ratio even we resize the browser window. But we can see unwanted space on top and bottom if browsers window height larger than width likewise spaces comes left and right if browsers window width is greater than height. I dont need that spaces.